# how to use hook_cron_queue_info in a custom module?

Tags: cron

I am retrieving remote data by clicking an update button. I want to make it automatic. I read many articles about it but I didn't find a good example for using hook_cron_queue_info in my module. can anybody help me?

Comment: There are working examples on [the docs page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7)...do they not work for you? If not, could you add some more information: show the code you've tried, and what errors were produced

Comment: I used the examples which has been on that page but nothing happened! no drupal message has been set after running the function. ok I will put some parts of my code since it is very long

Comment: Yeah some code will help a lot :) I'm a bit confused what you mean though, none of the examples on that page set a message of any kind...

Comment: `$function = 'itunesdec_batch_update_apps';
$_SESSION['http_request_count'] = 0; // reset counter for debug information.
$batch = $function();
batch_set($batch);`                                             this is what i use in my hook_form_submit. I want to do this b a cron automatically so that user won't be forced to do this job.

Comment: I found this http://drupal.org/project/examples very helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can look at the example code shown in the documentation from [hook_cron_queue_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7), which still needs an explanation on how it is used.

```
function hook_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['aggregator_feeds'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'aggregator_refresh',
    'time' => 60,
  );
  return $queues;
}
```

The code show is actually the implementation of `hook_cron_queue_info()` made from the Aggregator module. (See [aggregator_cron_queue_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!aggregator!aggregator.module/function/aggregator_cron_queue_info/7).)

"aggregator_feeds" is the name of a [Drupal queue](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7) that is filled with items that need to be processed; "aggregator_refresh" is the name of a function that will be called when Drupal executes cron tasks, once for each item contained in the "aggregator_feeds" Drupal queue. [aggregator_refresh()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!aggregator!aggregator.module/function/aggregator_refresh/7) gets the item taken from that Drupal queue as first parameter.

The question you would ask at this point is: When are the Drupal queue items added to the queue?

[The Aggregator module does that in its `hook_cron()` implementation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!aggregator!aggregator.module/function/aggregator_cron/7), but any function could add items to a Drupal queue, including other hooks (with the exception of `hook_cron_queue_info()` and similar hooks<sup>*</sup>), form submission handlers, page callbacks, or any function called from those functions.

<sup>*</sup> By "similar hooks" I mean all those hooks that return information, and that are not invoked to handle an event or after/before an event occurred/occurs (as in the case of [hook_node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7)). In the list of "similar hooks," I would add, for example:

- [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)
- [hook_entity_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7)
- [hook_field_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7)
- [hook_archiver_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_archiver_info/7)
- [hook_tokens_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7)

Comment: your answer made clear many things for me including the steps which happen in whole story. thanks a lot