# Hook_cron in drupal

Tags: 7, cron

In my custom form module submit handler, I have written the following code:

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
db_insert('bds_user_expiry')->fields(array(
'uid' =>$user_id,
'active_user'=>strtotime("now"),
))->execute();
drupal_set_message(t('You have successfully set the expiry date'));
}
}
```

Here `bds_user_expiry` is my custom table name. When I click on submit button $user_id and the current time will be stored in my table.Now I want to define this scenario in `hook_cron_queue_info()` so that whenever cron runs this snippet will also run. For this first I have to define `hook_cron()`, issue is how can I define the above function in `hook_cron`,

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
function my_module_cron(){
$result=db_insert('bds_user_expiry')->fields(array(
'uid' =>$user_id,
'active_user'=>strtotime("now"),
))->execute();
$result=db_query($query);
$queue=DrupalQueue::get("item");
foreach($result as $data){
$queue->createItem($data);
}
}
}
```

Is this right? Can I define hook_cron in submit handler?

**UPDATED(To check if my snippet runs with cron or not)**
Following code is written in my custom module file.
when cron runs value of uid from `bds_user_expiry` will be inserted in `my_cron_table` just to check if my code is working with cron or not, but neither it gives me any error nor successful result.

```
function user_form_expiry_form_cron(){
$new=db_select('bds_user_expiry', 'b')
->fields('b',array('uid'))
->execute()->fetchassoc();
//print_r($new);
$result=db_query($new);
$queue=DrupalQueue::get("item");
foreach($result as $data){
$queue->createItem($data);
}
}
function user_form_expiry_cron_form_queue_info(){
$queues=array();
$queues['item']=array(
"worker callback"=>"myfunc",
);
return $queues;
}
function myfunc($data){
db_insert('my_cron_table')->fields(array(
'uid' =>$data,
))->execute();
}
```

Comment: Nesting functions in PHP serves no purpose, it's pretty much a side-effect of the parser. If you ever find yourself asking "should this function be inside another function?" for _anything_, the answer's almost certainly "no", unless you're talking about a closure/anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the same snippet of code, you might refactor it into a separate function, and call it from both `mymodule_form_submit` and `mymodule_cron`. Something like the following:

```
function _mymodule_set_expiry_date() {
  db_insert('bds_user_expiry')->fields(array(
    'uid' =>$user_id,
    'active_user'=>strtotime("now"),
  ))->execute();
  drupal_set_message(t('You have successfully set the expiry date'));
}
```

And then, on your hooks:

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  _mymodule_set_expiry_date();
  // ... rest of your code
}

function mymodule_cron() {
  _mymodule_set_expiry_date();
  // ... rest of your code
}
```

You can see the following question on Drupal Answers for a more detailed explanation about `hook_cron` and `hook_cron_queue_info`: [how to use hook_cron_queue_info in a custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69332/how-to-use-hook-cron-queue-info-in-a-custom-module)

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanku @dinopmi for your reply, I did not use hook_cron before that's why I checked if any of my custom code is working with cron or not, for this I have updated my answer, can you please point out where is my mistake?

Comment: @nomeer: I think you will need to debug your calls to the db_* functions. For instance, you don't need to call `db_query()` after having called `db_select()`, you already have the results in the `$new` variable.

Comment: Yes that was my mistake, after fixing that mistake and ran cron, it successfully enter the value in my 2nd table as required but when I again try to run the cron it gives me the following error `There are security updates available for one or more of your modules or themes. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.`

Comment: When I used hardcoded value instead of $data in `myfunc` then it is working but with $data its not